# std::tr1 has not been declared

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I'm trying nth time to compile qt from source, this time with option configure -release -platform-win32
but I'm getting errors:
[image]

Anyone knows how to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of mingw32 gcc are you using - does it definitely include the tr1 headers? Is the QT source definitely including the ones it needs?

Comment: @Rup I'm using gcc 4.7, it looks like it has those headers

Comment: Yeah, I spotted too late it says `win32-g++-4.6` in your output anyway. It's trying to use `std::tr1::has_trivial_constructor` which should be declared in `type_traits`. However it looks like it's already trying to include this. You could perhaps edit the `#if`s in the file (or temporarily `#undef` one of the constants then redefine it at the end) so it uses its tr1-not-available code.

Comment: @Rup I've checked this file and there <type_traits> is: std::tr1::has... so I really don't know what to do

Comment: You could edit TypeTraits.h and edit all the `#if ...` lines to be `#if 0` so that it doesn't try to use the tr1 classes. Alternatively you can try and figure out why the class isn't getting defined - I'm not sure what to suggest, I doubt the `-E` switch to gcc (to get the preprocessed output) will give you much useful.

Comment: You might want to try putting a `#include <tr1/type_traits>` at the top of the `TypeTraits.h` file so you get a set of those classes in the `std::tr1` namespace alongside the `std` namespace.  I'm sure there's a better fix, but I think that's a relatively easy workaround (if it works - I haven't tried it).

Answer (score 7):

You can run into this problem when compiling Qt with a MinGW compiler (maybe any gcc compiler) that defaults to compiling C++ programs with the C++11 standard enabled.

The 3rd party library JavaScriptCore tries to define some wrappers that 'normalize' `has_trivial_constructor` and related templates, but apparently it hasn't been been updated yet to deal with GCC's updates to incorporate the completed C++11 standard.

The fix is to use a MinGW compiler that doesn't enable C++11 features by default, or to turn them off by editing `mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf` to add the `-std=gnu++98` option to C++ builds:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS -std=gnu++98
#                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Great answer, fixed my qt make(4.8) in 2017 .

Comment: Made the analogous change in mkspecs\linux-g++\qmake.conf, it seems to have done the trick. (Still building)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gcc 4.7 you have access to most of C++11 if you compile with `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` you can check out the supported features under `std` namespace [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html). `tr1` sub namespace was for the draft which has been made standard now.

Comment: @aj I'm sorry but what your answer has to do with my question?

Comment: QT uses mingw, which wraps gcc, which needs `-std=gnu++11` or the new features will be undefined. If you don't use this option you will need to remove anything referenced which is not C++03 conforming in order to compile.

Comment: @aj the distro I'm using uses c++11 by default

Comment: Well in that case, I would've mentioned that in the first place. Can you update the question with your compile and link command lines? It might take some of the guessing out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the preliminary `std::tr1::has_trivial_constructor` by the C++11 standardized `std::is_trivially_constructible`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_trivially_constructible .

Answer (score 0):

Try (wrapped in the macro around `#include <type_traits>`) adding
`#include <tr1/memory>` in TypeTraits.h

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this very issue just by putting

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++98

in src/script/script.pro.  I hope it doesn't cause any problems to have compiled some of the compilation units c++-11 and other gnu++98.