# why putenv() is not declared?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to compile Qt 4.8.4 on Windows using GCC 4.7.1 (MinGW). I edited mkspec to include C++11 features (added `-std=c++11` flag) to get Java Script compiled (that module uses some tr1 features discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354371/stdtr1-has-not-been-declared)) unfortunately enabling C++11 somehow removes `putenv()` function from C library, that QtCore fails to compile without.

Comment: Are you including cstdlib?

Comment: I don't know! I'm compiling Qt itself.

Comment: @sorush-r, does it compile well without `-std=c++11` and turned off `javascript` module?

Comment: @maverik didn't tried and can't reconfigure right now. Compilation takes about 4.5 to 5 hours on my pc to finish.

Comment: @sorush-r, but looks like you don't have another way. It may tooks days to figure out what is happening. What is your version of glibc?

Comment: @maverik I'm using MinGW suite from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html GCC 4.7.1 and binutils 2.23.1. Can't find version of glibc (Normally I don't use MinGW nor windows)

Comment: `-std=gnu++11` may helps, but I don't check if it is.

Comment: started to compile again. I will come back when completed

Comment: You know that putenv is POSIX? And that Windows is not really POSIX?

Comment: @PlasmaHH yeah. And I'm also doing DBus and Pthreads on Windows. Problem?

Comment: `putenv` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, not `<cstdlib>`. C++ doesn't know about it, it has to come from the C library directly. You might need to compile with some preprocessor flag to enable POSIX extensions.

Comment: @larsmans: In the C++ libraries that typically come with g++, stdlib.h is included by cstdlib.

Comment: Now it says `std::tr1` has not been declared

Comment: @phresnel: but there's no requirement that they do, so it's worth trying to comply with the relevant standards to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it's named `_putenv`. The leading underscore correctly signals that it's not a standard C function but an implementation extension. You might be able to get away with `/Dputenv=_putenv`

Comment: Adding `-std=gnu++11` now I'm getting another error. See comments

Comment: @sorush-r: Because of the `/D` ? That would surprise me. If it's unrelated question, please make it another question.